# How to handle dependencies between branches in git-flow?

Tags: git, branching, gitflow

I've been working on feature_A while another dev works on feature_B. Now, the other dev needs a small functionallity that's implemented in my feature_A, but I've not finished the whole feature itself. How should I share the code to the other dev? Is it against git-flow branching model? Can I simply merge feature_A into feature_B?

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64670920/how-to-handle-dependecies-between-branches-in-git-flow "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Comment: @gnat Ok, sorry. And what about answer the question?

Comment: Work in the same branch temporarily? That's the closest to being collaborative as I see it instead of rushing changes for pulling. We're mercurial-based instead of git-based but I would think git would allow that quite easily. Actually I've really enjoyed those rare cases where me and another dev colloborate within the same branch. It streamlines the communication before we merge everything.

Answer (score 1):

Publish a stub.

It might only exist in unit test code but get it out there fast so feature B can see what to expect from feature A. If you discover that the stub must change while you develop then inform the feature B team as quick as you can. Try hard not to change the stub but accept that no amount of hand wringing will ensure it can’t happen.

Communicate all this clearly and put the stub somewhere people can pull it. Likely on a branch that would make a good merge target for both features.